# Reset Git repository permission

Tags: git

I made a mistake today and performed a chmod 0644 in my git repository and soon I started getting permission errors. I had to chmod the .git directory to 0777 before I could use the repository again. I compared the file permission with another git repo and found that different files have different permission in .git directory (default). Will the current 0777 create any problem in future? How can I reset the repo to default permissions?

*I am referring to the files in the .git repository and not the files under version control*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that could cause a problem is the hooks directory, because when the scripts have an executable flag, they will be executed. So I would remove the executable flag from those files.

I don't think other files are a problem other then that every use on your computer can read and alter them.

You can clone the repository to create a new repo with all the correct rights set. But you have to manually copy the `.git/config` file over to the new repository, because that doesn't get copied over.

Answer (score 3):

Been there, done that. What I did was dump the history of the repo (changesets/patches really), create a new empty repo and load the changesets with date/timestamps. Worked like a charm. I'm sure there are easier methods though.

Comment: If the repository is still working, you could just clone the repository.

Comment: Good point! Wish I had thought of that. Though, for me the fix was done in about 1.5 minutes, and that included googling. ;)

Comment: Thanks Ikke. Never thought about that :)